# Relationship with Enumerated Type in Java

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enumeration, relationship

I'm trying to create a many-to-many relationship between two types of which one is an Enumerated type. Lets say the first model is User and the second model is Role. A user can have many roles and a role can belong to many users.

I'd like to be able to write simple code like:

```
if (user.getRoles().contains(Role.ADMIN)) {
  //do something
}
```

Does anyone know if this is possible? I've seen that there is an @Enumerated Hibernate annotation but this doesn't look to be of use to me.

I've currently implemented a solution by created a model for a link table but this is very messy. Any help much appreciated.

-gearoid

**UPDATE:** Can someone specify how to persist an EnumSet on a model? The info above still stands, I wish to create a ManyToMany relationship with an Enumerated Type.

Comment: Why doesnt @Enumerated fit your needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found a good solution to the problem. If I keep my Enumerated Type as something simple such as:

```
public enum Role implements Serializable{

    USER, MODERATOR, ADMIN;

}
```

And then on my User model I create a Set of Roles with the @CollectionOfElements so it looks something like this:

```
  @CollectionOfElements(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  public Set<Role> getRoles() {
      return roles;
  }

  public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
      this.roles = roles;
  }
```

Hibernate seems to create a table for this relationship (called user_roles) which works as I'd like (A regular manyToMany relationship).

Hope this helps someone.

-gearoid.

Answer (score 2):

Have you had a look at the [EnumSet](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) class? This can store multiple Enum instances in a collection you can call `contains()` on

Comment: Thanks - I dont suppose you have any example of where the EnumSet is used in a many-to-many relationship?

Comment: Can't you add an EnumSet instance to the User and Role enums, holding instances of the other type?

Comment: Well, the enumerated type is only on one side of the relationship. Lets just say I simply had an EnumSet on the User model (forget about the Role model for now) - how would this get persisted?

I've tried to implement it but am getting an error saying that the "Data too long for column" when I try to save...

Answer (score 0):

We usually create subclasses [EnumUserType](https://www.hibernate.org/272.html) and then specify this class in the mapping file.